# Input-Output parameter

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have something like this,

```
 def input-output parameter table for tt1.
```

Please can you explain what input-output param is and how to use it in simple terms , The Definition is not really making sense at this moment in time.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An input output parameter is a parameter that is passed to a procedure that can then be updated and passed back. In this case you will receive a temp-table as a parameter that you could update and is then passed back.

Comment: Thank you very much